# Pandas TypeError: cannot label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>

Tags: python, pandas

So the code I'm working with is attempting to put year and quarter into a dataframe, as in 2020Q1, 2020Q2 etc.  But I'm getting a type error and I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [0] of <class 'int'> 
19 for i in range(0,len(crisis_df)):
 ---> 20     date_idx = 
pd.to_datetime(crisis_df.loc[i,'SERVICE_DATE'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
 21     crisis_df.loc[i,'Quarter'] = str(date_idx.year) + "Q" + str(date_idx.quarter)
```

Image attached.  Any help is appreciated!

image description [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/923CZ.png)